# command execution order within For loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

complete beginner to c# so please be nice!

I'm doing an online tutorial and I have a simple For loop routine as follows:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" "); 
        Console.WriteLine("C# code tutorial - day 1"); 
        Console.WriteLine(" "); 
        
for(int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
{
    if(i % 2 == 1) Console.WriteLine("i is even: " + i);
    else Console.WriteLine("i is odd");
}
}
}
```

but the output isn't quite what I want:

> C# code tutorial - day 1
>
> i is even: 1
>
> i is odd
>
> i is even: 3
>
> i is odd
>
> i is even: 5
>
> i is odd
>
> i is even: 7
>
> i is odd
>
> i is even: 9
>
> i is odd
>
> i is even: 11
>
> i is odd
>
> i is even: 13
>
> i is odd
>
> i is even: 15
>
> i is odd

I suspect it's executing the commands not quite in the order I want it to, but I've no idea how to fix it.

Ideas please...

Comment: tutorial day 0 should had been how to indent code properly for readability.

Answer (score 4):

the case for even is when it has 0 as reminder when divided by 2. So:

```
if(i % 2 == 0) 
{
  Console.WriteLine($"i is even: {i}");
}
else 
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{i} is odd");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  It was my misunderstanding of the "%" symbol that was at fault here!  I didn't realise it meant "remainder"!

Answer (score 0):

`if(i % 2 == 1)` is interpreted as divide by two and check that the remainder is 1. That means `i` is an odd number and not even as indicated in your code.